# Custom getter/setter not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

I have a property that sometimes needs to be a strong reference, and other times needs to be a weak reference. I thought I'd cracked it with the following custom getter/setter:

```
- (PropertyData *)property
{
    return _strongProperty? _strongProperty : _weakProperty;
}

- (void)setProperty:(PropertyData *)newProperty
{
    _strongProperty = newProperty;
    _weakProperty = nil;
}

- (void)weaken
{
    if (_strongProperty != nil) {
        _weakProperty = _strongProperty;
        _strongProperty = nil;
    }
}
```

Previously there was an ivar called `property` and an `@synthesize property`. I removed both and replaced with:

```
PropertyData __weak *_weakProperty;
PropertyData *_strongProperty;
```

The class using this class calls `weaken` when it wants to convert to a weak reference to prevent a retain cycle.

This all works fine on iOS, but running the same code on OS X doesn't work at all. In the debugger, `setProperty:` has no effect on either of the new ivars right from the outset, and it crashes before `weaken` is ever called.

I'm confused about whether you need a `@synthesize a=b` statement when writing custom getter/setters (deployment target OS X 10.10). Not obvious how to do that in this case because there are two backing ivars.

Comment: You do not need `@synthesize` if you are declaring your own ivar and custom getters and setters.

Comment: The above works fine for me. El Cap, Xcode 7.1. Could you please be more specific about the error you are getting?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I am really curious as to what use case you could possibly have for this "feature".

Comment: @NicholasH. Thanks for trying it! Breakpoints in `setProperty` are hit, but the two assignments have no effect and consequently a message send on `property` results in EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x27)

Comment: I just discovered that the OS X version of this project is targeting 32 bit only and ARC is disabled (and can't be enabled on 32 bit, apparently?). Sorry everyone. Not sure whether to delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the conventions, or you confuse anyone including yourself.

Start your instance variables with an underscore. Don't use synthesise.

Apart from that, you have two problems. One, calling weaken twice sets the property to nil. Second, there's a good chance that your property has only one reference count and goes away when you call weaken.

Comment: Good calls, thanks; code and question edited accordingly. And +1 for no 'z' in synthesise. Hasn't solved the problem though.

Comment: I just discovered that the OS X version of this project is targeting 32 bit only and ARC is disabled (and can't be enabled on 32 bit, apparently?). Sorry everyone. Not sure whether to delete the question.